# Photon, how to display nickname of more than two players?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I want the nicknames of the players to be displayed, but there is a problem, only the nickname of the owner and one player who joined is displayed normally, when a third player joins the room, his nickname replaces the nickname of the first player who joined. I make the owner's nickname through PhotonNetwork.Nickname, and the nickname of the player who logged in through PunRPC. Most guides do this, but it only works for two.

Answer (score 1):

Nicknames are accessible through `Player.NickName`, there's no reason to use RPCs for setting nicknames.

Simply get a player instance, either by looping through `PhotonNetwork.PlayerList` or a callback such as `OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player)` (from [IInRoomCallbacks](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/interface_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_i_in_room_callbacks.html)) and populate your nickname list from there.

See: [Player Class Reference](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html#a1024de23fed2d6df0a2850c11032b6cc)

Comment: Can you send part of code, because for me it’s doesn’t works

Comment: @Jouki there isn't enough information about your specific problem for me to add any code.

Comment: `code` void Start()
    {OwnerName.text = PhotonNetwork.NickName; }
    public void SetJoinedName(string nameIn)
    {
        if (JoinedName.text.Length <= 0 && OwnerName.text.Length > 0)
        {
            JoinedName.text = nameIn;
        }
        else if (JoinedName.text.Length > 0 && OwnerName.text.Length > 0)
        {
            JoinedName1.text = nameIn;
        }
        if (JoinedName.text.Length > 0 && OwnerName.text.Length > 0 && JoinedName1.text.Length > 0)
        {
            JoinedName2.text = nameIn;
          //its doesnt work its my 4th player
 }}`code`